# Xamarin form app: Keyboard type telephone allow to input negative values in Android but not in IOS

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have made an application in Xamarin From. Design the UI in xaml. My issue is when i define the Keyboard telephone in entry field it allow to input negative value in android app but in IOS it not allowed.

```
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Entry Text="{Binding Item.TextProvider2017}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Small" WidthRequest="140" MinimumWidthRequest="60" Placeholder="For 2017" Keyboard="Telephone" Completed="NoOfProvider_Completed" Unfocused="NoOfProvider_Unfocused"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Item.TextProvider2018}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Small" WidthRequest="140" MinimumWidthRequest="60" Placeholder="For 2018" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Item.TextProvider2019}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Small" WidthRequest="140" MinimumWidthRequest="60" Placeholder="For 2019" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
            <Entry Text="{Binding Item.TextProvider2020}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Small" WidthRequest="140" MinimumWidthRequest="60" Placeholder="For 2020" Keyboard="Telephone"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Keypad in Android:
[image]

Keypad in IOS:
[image]

In Android keypad have negative sign but IOS don't have. IS there any way to make both same.

Answer (score 1):

*This is the old answer, see below for an updated version*

You're going to want to create a [custom renderer](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/) for the `Entry` control which has the default behavior for UWP and Android, while adding a custom `InputAccessoryView` to your iOS `UITextField`.

Here's what your custom renderer for iOS might look like:

```
class MinusButtonEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if (Control == null) return;

        UIBarButtonItem button = new UIBarButtonItem("-", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) =>
        {
            var position = Control.SelectedTextRange.Start;
            var idx = (int) Control.GetOffsetFromPosition(Control.BeginningOfDocument, position);
            Element.Text.Insert(idx, "-");
        });
        UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar()
        {
            Items = new [] { button }
        };
        Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
    }
}
```

This code basically creates a button, adds that to a toolbar, and then assigns that toolbar to the underlying `UITextField`. You will of course want to customize the toolbar and toolbar button to suit your needs.

**EDIT:**

There's a better way to do this using [Effects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/effects/introduction/) in Xamarin Forms.

This class goes in the iOS project and is the main effect:

```
using MyApp;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly:ResolutionGroupName("Xamarin")]
[assembly:ExportEffect(typeof(MinusButtonEntryEffect), "MinusButtonEntryEffect")]
namespace MyApp
{
    public class MinusButtonEntryEffect : PlatformEffect<UIView, UITextField>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            if (Control == null) return;
            var element = Element as Entry;
            if (element == null) return;

            UIBarButtonItem button = new UIBarButtonItem("-", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) =>
            {
                var position = Control.SelectedTextRange.Start;
                var idx = (int)Control.GetOffsetFromPosition(Control.BeginningOfDocument, position);
                element.Text = element.Text.Insert(idx, "-");
            });
            UIToolbar toolbar = new UIToolbar()
            {
                Items = new[] { button }
            };
            Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
        }

        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
            Control.InputAccessoryView = null;
        }
    }
}
```

This code goes in the PCL and allows us to access the effect from XAML:

```
public class MinusButtonEntryEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public MinusButtonEntryEffect () : base ("Xamarin.MinusButtonEntryEffect") { }
}
```

So your XAML would look something like this:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Item.TextProvider2017}" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" FontSize="Small" WidthRequest="140" MinimumWidthRequest="60" Placeholder="For 2017" Keyboard="Telephone">
    <Entry.Effects>
        <local:MinusButtonEntryEffect />
    </Entry.Effects>
</Entry>
```

Make sure that `local` is whatever namespace your effect is in, for example:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp"
```

Comment: Thanks Micah for your replay, I am beginner  in Xamarin so please tell me where i write this code. in .iOS part or Common code.

Comment: @user2017279 please see my updated answer. I have provided a simpler way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried your updated code it compiled but when i run IOS app on simulator, App crashed after launch.

Comment: @user2017279 could you share the updated code that you're using along with any exceptions that cause it to crash? Thanks